# Enable ssl on open ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a requirement to add ssl on ldap because the application use port 636. My question is both 636/ 3268 can enable same time or not? I havr multiple applications use one need regular 636 othet 3268. I am wobdering I need to build secondary ldap for ssl or can you the existing one?

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 0):

A single OpenLDAP server daemon can listen on multiple ports (and sockets), even using different protocols, all at the same time.

The details of how this will be handled depend on how your OpenLDAP server is packaged.
For instance, under CentOS7 you would modify `SLAPD_URLS` in `/etc/sysconfig/slapd`.